# Does going down property imply a corresponding map is open without "finiteness"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Does the following proposition hold?

Proposition

Let f:A$\rightarrow$B be a ring homomorphism

If f has going down property then the corresponding map
$f^*$:Spec B$\rightarrow$Spec A is open map.

I know if we add the hypothesis that A is noetherian and B is finitely generated over A, this proposition holds.

Or is there a "minimal" hypothesis where this proposition holds.

Comment: A localisation is an easy counterexample; for instance $\mathbf Z \to \mathbf Q$. It is flat, satisfies going down, but is not open. You can produce slightly more interesting examples by inverting infinitely many (but not all) primes. On the other hand, a *finitely presented* map is open if and only if it satisfies going down; see \[Tags [00I1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00I1) and [0407](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0407)\].

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'm surprised Chevalley's Theorem doesn't need notherian hypothesis.

Comment: Is there any counterexample which is finite type.

Comment: Sure, you can take any flat closed immersion that is not a clopen immersion; see for instance \[Tag [052H](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/052H)\], and see \[Tag [04PQ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04PQ)\] for more context about this type of phenomenon.

Comment: Re Chevalley's theorem: almost any theorem you can prove for finitely generated extensions $R \to S$ of Noetherian rings also holds for finitely presented extensions $R \to S$ of arbitrary (commutative) rings, by Noetherian approximation. The point is that if $R \to S$ is finitely presented, there exists a finitely generated subring $R_0 \subseteq R$ and a ring map $R_0 \to S_0$ such that $R \to S$ is the base change of $R_0 \to S_0$ along $R_0 \to R$.